# sqlite: insert complete text file into record field

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've seen various discussions of "importing text files into sqlite," but they all seem to mean the text file should be taken line-per-line and inserted into individual records. I, however, want to move the entire contents of a text file into an individual record, say into a column called FileCont NVARCHAR(MAX). So, for example, I've got 50 text files and they should go into 50 individual records of a table. Obviously I don't want to cram all of the actual text into an INSERT statement -- or do I? It would be best if the INSERT statement had some sort of placeholder, i.e.,

```
INSERT INTO tbl (... FileCont ...) VALUES (... $text-file-contents ...);
```

My Plan-B would be just to store a link to the actual text file in each record, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing pure SQLite SQL code as a script and submitting it directly to SQLite?  Then, yes, you will need to write the `INSERT` statements containing the entire contents of each file you want to store.

If you're issuing the `INSERT` statements from another language (Python, PHP, etc) then you can use *parameterized* statements and load each text file into a string variable.

Comment: Thanks. I sort of know what you mean, but could you give me an example of, say, PHP using such parameterized statements?

Comment: Note that if the file contains NULs, inserting it as a string rather than a blob will result in the file being truncated at the first NUL.

Comment: I'm guessing something like this: $q = "INSERT INTO " . TB_PREFIX . "mdata values (... $big_text ...)"; but as a PHP beginner (this project has to be Web-based), I'm not sure how to attach the text contents to $big_text.

Comment: @user78162 The question did not mention PHP (and it still does not).